# substituting some elements of a matrix with new values bash

Tags: arrays, bash, file, matrix, sed

I am trying to read in a file, change some parts of it and write it to a new file in bash. I know that I can substitute the parts with the "sed" command but I do not know how to it in my case which is a matrix in the beginning of my file. Here is how my file looks like

```
alpha
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1 
some text here
more numbers here
```

and I am trying to substitute the values of the matrix above in a for loop like

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 
do
replace 1 0 0
        0 1 0   
        0 0 1
 by     1*(1+${i})  ${i}/2  0
        ${i}/2         1    0
        0              0    1
and print the whole file with the substitution to newfile.${i}
done
```

I want to do this in bash. Any idea how to do this? And I only want to change this part and only this part!

Comment: Do you know the position and the size of the matrix ?

Comment: @Lord of dark You mean the whole file or just this part that I want to change? the matrix is 3by3 , exactly like the example, and starts from the third line of the file to the 5th line. This is very specific and it needs to be in this format in order to be read by a software package that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk is more suitable for this:

```
for i in {1..4}; do awk -v i="$i" -f substitute.awk oldfile.txt > newfile.$i; done
```

using the following `substitute.awk` script:

```
{
 if( NR == 3 ) { print 1 + i, i / 2, 0 }
 else if( NR == 4 ) { print i / 2, 1, 0 }
 else print $0
}
```

(assuming, as you wrote, that the matrix is always in lines 3 through 5; in your example it is in lines 2 through 4)

Comment: thank you for the answer. Yes it is always from line 3 to 5! The example was just to show what I meant! =)